# Android - Formas diferentes de "setar" um listener em objetos

Tags: android, sintaxe, listener

Existe uma forma diferente (Sintaxe) de "setar" um listener em um objeto no Android ? Por exemplo, apenas conheço essa forma:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activity.onBackPressed(-1);             
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É também possível atribuir o `clickEvent` no *xml*:

```
<Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="OK"
     android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Na *Activity* implemente um método chamado *onClick* que recebe uma *View*:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    activity.onBackPressed(-1);             
}
```

O nome do método pode ser um qualquer, desde que seja igual ao indicado no *xml*.

Outra forma é a própria *Activity* implementar a *interface* `OnClickListener`:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);

        button2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if((Button)v == button1{
            //O button1 foi clicado
        }
        if((Button)v == button2{
            //O button2 foi clicado
        }
    }
}
```