# Reutilizar código no onClick de vários botões

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, button

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo onde ele conterá vários botões.

Preciso da sua ajuda para ver se consigo melhorar o código.

As ações fazem a mesma coisa apenas mudam a cor de fundo e me passam qual o valor do botão.

O aplicativo possui várias outras telas que possuem muitos botões com quase as mesmas ações, apenas com algumas alterações no retorno.

[image: (Imagem) Estou usando layout linear]

Meu código:

```
btnBall01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    count1++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall01.getId());
                    btnBall01.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall01.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityMegasenaCreateGame.this, "Verde " + games.getActualNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (count1 != 1){
                        count1 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall01.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                         Toast.makeText(ActivityMegasenaCreateGame.this, "Branco " + games.getActualNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btnBall02.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count2++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall02.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall02.getText().toString());

                    if (count2 != 1){
                        count2 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall02.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall03.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count3++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall03.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall03.getText().toString());

                    if (count3 !=1){
                        count3 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall03.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall04.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall04.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count4++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall04.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall04.getText().toString());

                    if (count4 != 1){
                        count4 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall04.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }

                }
            });

            btnBall05.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall05.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count5++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall05.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall05.getText().toString());

                    if (count5 != 1){
                        count5 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall05.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall06.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall06.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count6++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall06.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall06.getText().toString());

                    if (count6 != 1){
                        count6 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall06.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall07.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall07.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count7++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall07.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall07.getText().toString());

                    if (count7 != 1){
                        count7 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall07.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall08.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall08.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count8++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall08.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall08.getText().toString());

                    if (count8 != 1){
                        count8 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall08.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall09.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall09.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count9++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall09.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall09.getText().toString());

                    if (count9 != 1){
                        count9 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall09.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall10.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count10++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall10.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall10.getText().toString());

                    if (count10 != 1){
                        count10 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall10.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall11.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count11++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall11.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall11.getText().toString());

                    if (count11 != 1){
                        count11 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall11.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall12.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count12++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall12.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall12.getText().toString());

                    if(count12 != 1){
                        count12 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall12.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall13.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count13++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall13.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall13.getText().toString());

                    if(count13 != 1){
                        count13 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall13.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall14.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count14++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall14.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall14.getText().toString());

                    if (count14 != 1){
                        count14 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall14.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sabia que:

1. um mesmo método pode ser associado ao evento de click de vários botões?
2. num array podem ser guardados valores diferentes, que podem ser acedidos através de um índice?
3. num objecto da classe View pode ser guardada uma referência a um qualquer objecto?

Agora que sabe, é fácil resolver o problema.

(1) permite ter apenas um método para tratar o click de todos os botões.
(2) permite guardar todos os contadores numa variável.
(3) permite guardar a posição no array onde está guardado o valor do contador correspondente a esse botão.

O método tem de ter uma assinatura do tipo:

```
public void nomeMetodo(View button)
```

O método é atribuído a cada evento de click usando o atributo `android:onClick`, na declaração de cada botão no XML:

```
android:onClick="nomeMetodo"
```

O array deve ser do tipo int e ter o número de itens igual ao número de botões.

Na declaração de cada botão, no XML, use o atributo `android:tag` para guardar a posição, no array, do seu contador.

```
android:tag="0"
```

Use 0 para o botão1, 1 para o botão2 e assim por diante.

No java, dentro do método `nomeMetodo`, esse valor pode ser obtido com

```
int tag = (int)button.getTag();
```

Use-o no array para obter o valor do contador.

Informação complementar:

- [Qual objetivo dos métodos setTag e getTag na View?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215934/2541)
- [Android - Formas diferentes de “setar” um listener em objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49397/2541)

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um método, com todo esse código repetitivo, e cada vez que precisar dele é só chama-lo, e como você quer um retorno de um numero é só definir o tipo de método como int ou double e fazer o retorno no final, e coloque como parâmetros o que precisar dentro do método, talvez vc tenha pensar um pouco para criar um "método universal" para todos os seus botões

```
public int meuMetodo(int parametro){
  int numero=2;
  int resultado=numero+parametro;
  return resultado;
}
```

Fiz só um exemplo pq não entendi o que realmente você quer como retorno, mas espero que tenha te ajudado